# Parse Json objects with different types using gson

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

I have the following json from the Server. It is a json array with different objects. I want to identify the user objects based on the key "type" and add them to a user hashmap and fetch user to show information in my view containing the "payments" object. I am using gson and retrofit. TIA

```
"included":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "type":"payments",
         "attributes":{
            "amount_cents":100,
            "amount_currency":"INR",
            "description":"Test description!!",
            "created_at":"2016-03-01T11:30:53Z",
            "status":"paid",
            "paid_at":null,
            "charged_at":null,
            "formatted_amount":"Rs1.00"
         },
         "relationships":{
            "sender":{
               "data":{
                  "id":"2",
                  "type":"users"
               }
            },
            "receiver":{
               "data":{
                  "id":"1",
                  "type":"users"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "type":"users",
         "attributes":{
            "first_name":"Rob",
            "last_name":"Thomas"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"1",
         "type":"users",
         "attributes":{
            "first_name":"Matt",
            "last_name":"Thomas"
         }
      }]
```

My classes are

```
public class ActivityFeedItem implements IFeedItem {
    @SerializedName("id")
    String id;

    @SerializedName("type")
    String type;

    @SerializedName("attributes")
    Attributes attributes;

    protected class Attributes {
        double amount_cents;
        String amount_currency;
        String description;
        String created_at;
        String status;
        String paid_at;
        String charged_at;
        String formatted_amount;

        Relationships relationships;

        public double getAmount_cents() {
            return amount_cents;
        }

        public String getAmount_currency() {
            return amount_currency;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getCreated_at() {
            return created_at;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public String getPaid_at() {
            return paid_at;
        }

        public String getCharged_at() {
            return charged_at;
        }

        public String getFormatted_amount() {
            return formatted_amount;
        }

        public Relationships getRelationships() {
            return relationships;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UserFeedItem implements IFeedItem {

    @SerializedName("id")
    String id;

    @SerializedName("type")
    String type;

    @SerializedName("attributes")
    Attributes attributes;


    public class Attributes {
        @SerializedName("first_name")
        String first_name;

        @SerializedName("last_name")
        String last_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: loop through `included` array and add it to your user hashmap. just like @NoChinDeluxe doing , but now use gson class array.

Comment: In JSON object in the first Object attributes are different compared to second and third objects in that case how you can retrieve .In the iteration it'll find different keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy if you just put your JSON response String into a `JSONArray`. Then you can just access the `type` field and test if it's `users`. Like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourServerResponseString);
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    String type = object.getString("type");
    if(type.equals("users")) {
        //add to your users HashMap
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this method. But where do I do this if I am using Gson as gson handles the serialization of the objects?

Comment: Since your server response is JSON, you would essentially parse it out using the method above and extract the values you need to create your `ActivityFeedItem` and `UserFeedItem` objects. Then you would serialize them with Gson. Unless there's something I'm missing in what you're trying to do, in which case feel free to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an array of objects from you JSON using GSON as below

```
   Gson gson= new Gson();
   String jsonString= yourJsonObject.getString("included");
   ActivityFeedItem[] activityFeedArray=gson.fromJson(jsonString,ActivityFeedItem[].class);
```

Now your activityFeedArray contains all the feedItems you get in JSON. Then you can iterate through it as you would in any array and add to hashmap when type is user as below-

```
    for(ActivityFeedItem item:activityFeedArray) {
      if(item.type.equals("users")) {
        //add to your users HashMap
       }
    }
```